# Use a component in another component in ionic2

Tags: html, angular, ionic2

I have a component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'footer-component',
  templateUrl: 'footer.html'
})
export class FooterComponent {}
```

And would like to use that one in another like that

```
<ion-content>
  Hello
  <footer-component><footer-component/>
</ion-content>
```

I added both in my "@NgModule". Unfortunately I get this error :

> directive_normalizer.js:92Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Only
>   void and foreign elements can be self closed "footer-component"

Do you know why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set `<footer-component><footer-component/>`

Where `<footer-component/>` is recognized as a self closing tag (the `/>`) (like `<input/>`

To close a tag the `/` should be at the beginning of the closing element. (like you see in `</ion-content>`

So change your `<footer-component/>` to `</footer-component>`

Full code:

```
<ion-content>
  Hello
  <footer-component></footer-component>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Sometimes you spend so much time to easy things like that... Thanks !